# How to enable a disabled checkbox dynamically?

Tags: javascript, html

Please see here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nShQs/

Press the disable button and then the enable button. The checkbox doesn't get enabled.

HTML:

```
<input id="check" type="checkbox"/>
<input id="btn1" type="button" value="enable" />
<input id="btn2" type="button" value="disable" />
```

JS:

```
function enable() {
    var x = document.getElementById("check");
    alert(x.getAttribute("disabled"));
    x.setAttribute("disabled", "false");
    alert(x.getAttribute("disabled"));
}

function disable() {
    var x = document.getElementById("check");
    alert(x.getAttribute("disabled"));
    x.setAttribute("disabled", "true");
    alert(x.getAttribute("disabled"));
}
document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", enable);
document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", disable);
```

**answer**

As the answers tell it is because the `disabled` attribute is a boolean attribute.
See [here](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-microsyntaxes.html#boolean-attribute).

Comment: I chose PSL's answer because he answered 1st.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Just do

```
function enable() {
    document.getElementById("check").disabled= false;

}

function disable() {
     document.getElementById("check").disabled= true;
}
```

With this you are setting the property of the DOM element, while setting attribute presence of attribute `disabled` will disable the check box, so even if you do `x.setAttribute("disabled", "false");` it will still be there on the element as attribute.

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/CyVtb/)**

or you would just do:

```
function disable() {
    document.getElementById("check").setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
}

function enable() {
   document.getElementById("check").removeAttribute('disabled');
}
```

`disabled` as attribute and `disabled` as property are different.

Comment: Isn't it rather strange that the disabling depends on the presence of the attribute as opposed to its value?

Comment: @learner yeah that's the way it works.. :) infact you can see the source after disable-> enable. It will still have that attribute with your original code.

Comment: @PSL, is this strange behavior only seen in this attribute, or is it common in HTML? I don't see any benefit of this approach.

Comment: No it is common especially for these kind of boolean property values, i will find a link for you for refernce, diff between attr and properties

Comment: @learner some other attributes (like `readonly`) work the same way. It's sort of unexpected and you'll stumble upon these things mostly by accident. That said, if you stick to the corresponding properties they'll abstract away the weird attribute implementation.

Comment: @learner read the last section: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes

Comment: why we can not use `enabled=false` or `enabled=true` in stud of `disabled= false` and  `disabled= true`

Answer (score 9):

Set the `disabled` **property** rather than the **attribute** ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/nShQs/2/)).

```
function enable() {
    document.getElementById("check").disabled = false;    
}

function disable() {
    document.getElementById("check").disabled = true;
}
```

A control will remain disabled if the `disabled` **attribute** is present *at all* - regardless of its value ([fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/antisanity/73qRx/)). Setting the `disabled` **property** to `false` will remove the `disabled` **attribute**.

Answer (score 4):

It works,

```
 x.removeAttribute("disabled");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/maximos/89wxX/1/