# Jquery Button disabled and enabled when checkbox clicked

Tags: jquery, html

I am new to html and Jquery I am trying to create a project where in first I disable my Jquery Button first but when checkbox clicked it will be enabled however my code below is not working. The button is not disable always enable even my checkbox is uncheck. I would really appreciate any suggestion and help. Thanks a lot.

```js
function goFurther() {
  if (document.getElementById("chkAgree").checked == true) {
    $("#submit").disabled = false;
    $("#cancel").disabled = false;  
  } else {
    $("#submit").disabled = true;
    $("#cancel").disabled = true;
  }
}
```

```css
input[disabled] {
  color: gray;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" id="chkAgree" onclick="goFurther()">I agree.
  <br><br>
</form>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17599984/how-to-enable-a-disabled-checkbox-dynamically

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot set `disabled` on a jQuery wrapped element. Use [`prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) for it:

```
$("#submit").prop('disabled', false); // To enable the button
$("#submit").prop('disabled', true); // To disable the button
```

Alternatively, you can get the native DOM elements out of the jQuery wrapper using [`get()`](https://api.jquery.com/get/) and then assign `disabled`:

```
$("#submit").get(0).disabled = false; // To enable the button
$("#submit").get(0).disabled = true; // To disable the button
```

Comment: Thank you very much it still not working when I placed it in my code I really appreciate your help

Comment: @CLOUDS -- Please specify what's not working. It is too difficult to track down a bug without knowing much of your code. Did you see any error in console?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to disable checkbox with and without jquery like

```
document.getElementById("test").disabled= true;
$("#test").prop('disabled', true);
$("#test").attr('disabled', true);
```